# Exchange upgrade fails due to a replication issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, exchange-2013

I'm trying to upgrade an exchange 2013 server to CU18, but it's currently failing.

The error is...

> The server side error is: 0x21a2 The FSMO role ownership could not be
>   verified because its directory partition has not replicated
>   successfully with at least one replication partner.

Now this is a standalone server, however it originally did have a partner, but we ended up scrapping that.

I can see in active directory sites and services that it lists both itself and the server that was going to be its replica.

Can i just right click and delete that server from sites and services to proceed does anyone know?

I've had a bit of a search and everything suggests that i fix the replication before continuing... well thats easier said than done as the server that was going to be the replica doesnt exist any more.

any help appriciated.

Comment: Just to confirm, there is a server showing up in Sites and Services that doesn't exist right now?

Comment: exactly that... correct

Comment: If you aren't completely comfortable working in adsiedit, you may want to get a consultant.  If you are, time for some manual cleanup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll want to do the following for the server that has been removed:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/02/17/step-by-step-removing-a-domain-controller-server-manually/

> **Step 1: Cleaning up metadata via Active Directory Users and Computers**
>
> 1. Log in to DC server as Domain/Enterprise administrator and navigate to Server Manager > Tools > Active Directory Users and Computers
> 2. Expand the Domain > Domain Controllers
> 3. Right click on the DC server that need to remove manually and click delete
> 4. In next dialog box, click yes to confirm
> 5. In next dialog box, select This Domain Controller is permanently offline and can no longer be demoted using the Active Directory Domain Services Installation Wizard (DCPROMO) and click Delete
> 6. If the domain controller is global catalog server, in next window click yes to continue with deletion
> 7. If the domain controller holds any FSMO roles in next window, click ok to move them to the domain controller which is available
>
> **Step 2: Cleaning up the DC server instance from the Active Directory Sites and Services**
>
> 1. Go to Server manager > Tools > Active Directory Sites and Services
> 2. Expand the Sites and go to the server which need to remove
> 3. Right click and click Delete
> 4. In next window click yes to confirm
>
> **Step 3: Clean up metadata using ntdsutil**
>
> *NOTE: Windows Server 2003 or earlier used ntdsutil and was bit of challenge but this was later simplified*
>
> 1. Right Click on Start > Command Prompt (admin)
> 2. Type ntdsutil and enter
> 3. Then metadata cleanup
> 4. Next type `remove selected server <servername>`, replace `<servername>` with DC server to remove
> 5. In warning window click yes to proceed
> 6. Execute quit command twice

Comment: C:\setup>ntdsutil
ntdsutil: metadata cleanup
metadata cleanup: remove selected server HOSTEX-2
Binding to localhost ...
Connected to localhost using credentials of locally logged on user.
LDAP error 0x22(34 (Invalid DN Syntax).
Ldap extended error message is 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100225, problem 2006 (B
AD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'CN=Ntds Settings,HOSTEX-2'

Win32 error returned is 0x208f(The object name has bad syntax.)
)
Unable to determine the domain hosted by the Active Directory Domain Controller
(5). Please use the connection menu to specify it.

Comment: @John Trouble running NTDSUTIL could be a separate question. I would definitely try logging on to the currently running domain controller, running command prompt **as an administrator** and then trying NTDSUTIL again. If that's how you already did it, then either google that error or ask a new question about it.